# Subset multiple dataset in r using a loop

Tags: r, loops, dataset

I have one dataset (data1) with multiple PtIDs. I would like to create multiple subsets of 'data1' by each PtID for a few variables ( var1, var2).  I am using the following loop:

```
IDs<-unique(data1$PtID)
for (i in 1:length(IDs)){ 
  i<-data1[data1$PtID==IDs[i],c("PtID","var1","var2")]
}
```

However, this only create one dataset named 'i' for the last PtID.

Comment: Because you are just updating the i on each iteration.   If you need to create multiple objects, use `assign`

Comment: This seems like it would be easier to use `split(data1, data1$PtID)`. That will create a list of all the subsets without the need for a loop. Plus a list will make it much easier to further process the subsets.